# Base class field initialization in derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance

1) If I define a field in a base class like

```
myType myField = new MyField();
```

Will this field be always initialized in a derived class?

2) If I initialize this field through base class default (parameterless) constructor will it be initialized in a derived class?

Assuming I do not call any `:base()` constructors from derived type.

My point is to instantiate field with default value only in base class and provide overridden initialization in derived classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, fields will always be initialized. If you don't explicitly chain to any other constructors, you'll chain to `base()` implicitly. You'll always end up chaining right up the type hierarchy until you hit `Object`.

> My point is to instantiate property with default value only in base class and provide overridden initialization in derived classes.

Then I suggest in the base class, you have two constructors, one of them possibly protected:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private MyType myField;

    protected BaseClass(MyType myField)
    {
        this.myField = myField;
    }

    public BaseClass() : this(new MyType())
    {
    }
}
```

Then constructors from your derived types can chain to either constructor, as appropriate... and you don't end up creating an instance of `MyType` when you don't need to.